# is there a place to go to describe my function and see if it's even possible in wordpress?

Tags: discussion

I have a layout and reveal question and I don't know what it's called.  I'm not looking for plugin suggestions from you guys but I don't know what I'm looking for is called.  If I describe it, will people tell me what it's called so I can do my own google research and find tools to make what I need?

If that's not appropriate here, is there a place to go ask that it would be appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such (layout question) sounds a little removed from WordPress itself to make a good question on main site.

You could try [The Loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) (our chat room) to discuss your issue, it’s has no formal scope and more open to varied topics. :)